# data only container for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

Im having problems getting data only container working with elasticsearch.
I can get it to work where volume is a host volume but not for data only container.
Here is my data only container:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM busybox
VOLUME /src/elasticsearch/data
VOLUME /src/elasticsearch/log
VOLUME /src/elasticsearch/plugins
VOLUME /src/elasticsearch/config

ADD ./elasticsearch.yml /src/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
CMD /bin/sh
```

Build and run it:

```
docker build -t nmcg/my_data .
docker run -i -t -name my_data nmcg/my_data
```

Then I build my grafana dockerfile which includes elasticsearch

```
docker build -t nmcg/grafana:5.0 .
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 8000:8000 -p 9200:9200 -p 8125:8125/udp -p 8126:8126 --volumes-from metrics_data1 nmcg/grafana:5.0
```

and points to the elasticsearch.yml file when running elasticsearch:

```
exec start-stop-daemon --start --user "elasticsearch" -c "elasticsearch" --exec /elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch --"-Des.default.config=/src/elasticsearch/config/e.yml
```

However elasticsearch  fails to start:

```
2014-12-09 23:32:59,668 INFO success: elasticsearch entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2014-12-09 23:32:59,927 INFO exited: elasticsearch (exit status 3; not expected)
```

Any ideas? Cant understand why wont start as when I do host volumes with same paths it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ADD` line in your Dockerfile won't have any effect (the file won't be copied), as it appears after the VOLUME instructions. If you instead change it to appear *before* the VOLUME instructions, it will be copied into the volume.

You don't need to leave your data container running. If you just run a command that exits e.g. `docker run --name data-con data-container-image echo "Data Container"` it will create the volumes and exit. The volumes still exist and can be accessed with `--volumes-from data-con` in other containers. Just don't rm the data-con container.

Also, in general you don't need a separate Dockerfile for running containers and data containers - you may be able to use the grafana image as your data container as well.

In short:

- Move the ADD line to the top
- Remove the CMD line
- Launch data container with `docker run --name my_data nmcg/my_data echo "My Data Container`
- Check if you actually need a separate Dockerfile for your data container

For more information, you can have a look at my blog post here: http://container-solutions.com/2014/12/understanding-volumes-docker/

Answer (score 0):

I am not understanding clearly when are you running `exec start-stop-daemon --st...`

But you should try doing:

```
docker run -d \
    -p 80:80 -p 8000:8000 -p 9200:9200 -p 8125:8125/udp -p 8126:8126 \
    --volumes-from metrics_data1 nmcg/grafana:5.0 \
    /elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Des.default.config=/src/elasticsearch/config/e.yml
```

Which seems more like the regular "docker" approach.